# XAML StackPanel inner items size problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have this XAML code:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Miniaturas" Orientation="Vertical" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Margin="1">
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="VistaPrevia" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

What I'm trying to do is simulate two columns. Why? because **WindowsFormsHost** Can't be stored into **ColumnDefinition** it throws this error:

**Can't add value Type "WindowsFormHost" to a dictionary or collection of type "ColumnDefinitionCollection**.

Usually I Do this with this code:

```
        <Grid Margin="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="VistaPrevia" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
```

How can I do to obtaind the same efect without using **ColumnDefinition**

Note: I need two columns one with fixed width size and another that uses the remaining width of the window.

Comment: what do you mean by "WindowsFormsHost can't be stored into columndefinition"?

Comment: this throws an error "Can't add value Type "WindowsFormHost" to a dictionary or collection of type "ColumnDefinitionCollection".

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez have you tired `Grid` example from above? Are you sure you just did not forget to close `</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`? Error would suggest you tired to put `WindowsFormsHost` as another column definition

Comment: It is unclear, what exactly happens, in the stackpanel scenario, where you don't see the `WindowsFormsHost`? Doesn't that become the second column?

Comment: It works just fine on my computer. Could you add a complete example which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @dkozl You are right. But is really extrange. The error was fixed but it still appear on my error list. Thats why i take another path. To solve it. Re wrote my code and now it Works. I'm feelling bad now :{ some hour trying to fix something that was not wrong.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Design parse errors may be related to operations occurring when view models are instantiated and show up as errors. Once built sometimes those errors go away due to the not being in design mode.

Comment: @OmegaMan But it is quite extrange. it show an error that was fixed  even after many  recompilations. must be a bug in VS 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull down VS2013 express and see if that error has been fixed in the parser. Also verify you have installed update 4 for Visual Studio 2012 to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have seen occurs because you did something like this

```
    <Grid Margin="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="VistaPrevia" Width="Auto"/><!-- fail -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

P.S.: and the answer is use `Grid`.